# How to remove an Item from a combobox when a datasource is assigned to an enum?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

How to remove an Item from a combobox when a datasource is assigned to an enum?

When trying to remove by `Items.Remove`, got error:

> Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.

Any suggestion?

Note: I would keep using the enum because I deal it in many places in the code.

---

The code:

```
public enum DefaultValueType
{
    None = 0,
    Static = 1,
    Query = 2
}

cBoxDefaultType.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DefaultValueType));
```

In one case, I want to remove the Query item from the options of the combobox.

```
cBoxDefaultType.Items.RemoveAt(2); // Throw exception
```

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution by filtering the array of Enumeration:

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(DefaultValueType))
    .Cast<DefaultValueType>()
    .Where(p => p != DefaultValueType.Query)
    .ToArray<DefaultValueType>()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove item from `DataSource` and rebind or use just `.Items` without`DataSource`

In your case you need to convert Enum to array and then work with it.

Comment: I can't convert it because I'm using the Value (integer) instead of dealing with Strings

Comment: Ok, you can put values via foreach loop to the `Items` property, than `.Remove` will work, otherwise you can assign `var array = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DefaultValueType));` and then remove from array necessary value and assign to the `DataSource = array;`

Comment: Thanks for your second suggestion, I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Also for .NET 2.0 (Remove 'Invalid' item from enum 'SomeEnum'):

```
comboBox1.DataSource = Array.FindAll((SomeEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnum)),
(SomeEnum SM) => { return SM != SomeEnum.Invalid; });
```